# Kobo Aura and style

Tags: epub, kobo

I have created an ebook with a lot of figures, and Calibre viewer shows them correctly. A friend of mine however complained that many figures showed really large on his Kobo Aura One, and he sent me some pics (you may see them [here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOgZaBv5sXhaIg0ZtJF5CZnwrh9b_7Zm223x-48WCzfFbUPxikRyO8eRxpnxDFuTQ?key=STZfeWVBeHBPWGx1dklzS3l0bE8xSDhPX1FqUEJB)).

I had a quick look at the source: the figure is coded as

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p class="figura"><img alt="" src="../Images/q078a.png" width="70%"/></p>
  </div>

  <div class="BullProblema">
    <p><a href="../Text/aiutini.xhtml#a078">vuoi un aiutino?</a></p>
    <p><a href="../Text/soluzioni.xhtml#s078">vai alla risposta</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is

```
.figura { 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 1em; 
  padding: 0; 
  display: inline-block; }

.wrap {text-align: center; }

.BullProblema, .BullAiutino, .BullSoluzione { 
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: black;
}
```

It seems to me that the Kobo does not read the CSS: indeed, if I remove the line "display: inline-block;" from the CSS, Calibre reader also shows a large figure.

What did I wrong? My source contains the line

```
  <link href="../Styles/stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and stile.css is my actual stylesheet.

Comment: Interesting question, I have an Aura One and my complaint is always the opposite: Because of its high DPI, all illustrations are tiny. I hope it's related and that there is a solution.

Comment: Your html sample appears to be missing an opening `<div>` tag.

Comment: @rgchris: I just forgot to copy it: the epub is well formed.

Comment: did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: nope. The only guess I have is that Kobo did not read the CSS.